# Using Selenium with Java, Using dynamically drag-and-drop with attribute 'draggable'

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Recently I was trying to use the traditional drag-and-drop operation using 'Action' object, I tried it using it straight-forward afterwards I understood that the elements of which I want to drag are changing dynamically.

before the element looks like this:

```
<div data-v-a030b586 tabindex="-1" class="v-list-item theme--light">...</div>
```

after clicking on the element it changes to:

```
<div data-v-a030b586 tabindex="-1" class="v-list-item theme--light" draggable="false">...</div>
```

When holding the element it changes to:

```
<div data-v-a030b586 tabindex="-1" class="v-list-item theme--light sortable-chosen" draggable="true">...</div>
```

I tried to do this by using this code:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class*='row']:nth-child(2) [class*='col-md']:nth-child(3) div[tabindex='-1'] div[class='v-list-item__icon icon-item-wrap'] i"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        for(WebElement elem: elems){
            System.out.println(elem.getText());
            elem.click();
        }
        elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[draggable]"));
        WebElement sourceElm = elems.get(2);
        WebElement destElm = elems.get(0);
        builder.clickAndHold(sourceElm);
        builder.clickAndHold(destElm);

        builder.clickAndHold(sourceElm).moveToElement(destElm).click().release(destElm).build().perform();
```

But as I tried it nothing is happening. What is wrong ? or what is the correct way of doing it, if possible of course...?

**************************** EDIT *********************************
This is how the dom looks when you hold an element of if clicking on it as I described above:
[image]

Comment: can you share a link to the page?

Comment: unfortunately I can't since you will have VPN access in order to get into the system.